# $2$-Sylow subgroups and $3$-Sylow subgroups of $A_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

I am working on finding all $2$- and $3$-Sylow subgroups of $A_{4}$.
The answer I got is:

$2$-Sylow : $\langle(12)(34), (14)(23)\rangle$

$3$-Sylow : $\langle(123)\rangle, \langle(124)\rangle, \langle(134)\rangle, \langle(234)\rangle$

Is the answer right and exhaustive? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Read the answers of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990541/find-the-subgroups-of-a4/993149). It gives all $p$-Sylow subgroups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the full list. They're isomorphic to *Klein's ViererGruppe*:

- $\bigl\{(), (12), (34), (12)(34)\bigr\}$,
- $\bigl\{(), (13), (24), (13)(24)\bigr\}$,
- $\bigl\{(), (14), (23), (14)(23)\bigr\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Remember third Sylow theorem, in particular

$$n_p | m, n_p \equiv 1 \mod p$$

and revise your answer for $p=2$

Comment: Thanks! Can you show me the third one?