# Alternating groups, $A_3$ and $A_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

I have to:

1. Prove that $A_3$ is a simple group.
2. Prove that $A_4$ is not a simple by proving that the elements of order $2$ along with the neutral form a normal subgroup.

I know that the elements of $A_3$ are $\{1,(123),(132)\}, $ but how is $A_3$ a simple group then?

Comment: $A_3$ has order $3$. It really can't have very many subgroups.

Comment: 1) Every group of prime order is simple by Lagrange. 2) $V_4$ is a normal subgroup of $A_4$ - see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990541/find-the-subgroups-of-a4).

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

$A_3$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_3$ since the order is $3$. Thus there are no other proper non-trivial normal subgroups. Hence $A_3$ is a simple group. In general, $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is simple for any prime $p$.